# Determine the language of the NPDA

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have to write the language of the below $NPDA$(Non-Deterministic Push Down Automata).
[image]

I think that from $q_0$ to $q_1$ and then $q_2$, we are actually building the below all the strings of $0$'s and $1$'s of the form $a^nb^n$ with the lenght at least 2.

But there is also a transition from $q_2$ to $q_0$, which makes a cycle, and it just read a $1$ from input string.
For example these strings are accepted by this machine, and the point is that in all of them the last character is $0$.

1100 1 10 1 1100

111000 1 1100 1 10

1100

But, unfortunatly I don't know how to write its language accuratly. My idea was to write something like the below language:

$L = \{ w(1^n) z (0^n) | w ∈ L \}$ and $z ∊ \{1,ɛ \}$

But it is not correct. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Isn't a NPDA a non-deterministic pushdown (rather than finite) automaton?

Comment: Yes. You are right, sorry, it was a mistake.@Nathaniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $L = \{1^n0^n\mid n>0\}$. It seems that the language of your PDA is $L(1L)^*$.

It is not exactly the way you wanted, but I think it is an accurate and short way to write it.

You could be a bit more verbose and write it as:

$$\{1^{n_1}0^{n_1}11^{n_2}0^{n_2}1…11^{n_k}0^{n_k}\mid k \geqslant 1 \wedge \forall i\in \{1, …, k\}, n_i > 0\}$$

Comment: I think because of the cycle we should use recursion in our language. But are we allowed to use of $*$ sign in our set?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to work with  an string such as $w$, because we have been told that we can not use of $*$ sign in our set

Comment: Not in the way you want, because if $u$ is a word, $u^*$ is a regular expression that is considered as a set, so something like $\{u^*\mid u \in L \}$ would be a set of sets of words.

Comment: @AylinNaebzadeh I edited the answer.

Comment: But I think each $1$ between $1^n0^n$ is not necessary.

Comment: Can we now create a new variable like $z$, and assign $\{ 1, ɛ \}$ to it? and then write it instead of $1$'s, between $1^n0^n$ pairs?

Comment: @AylinNaebzadeh The $1$ between is necessary, because the transition from $q_2$ to $q_0$ has to read a $1$. There is no $\varepsilon$-transition from $q_2$ to $q_0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135962/discussion-between-aylin-naebzadeh-and-nathaniel).